# Inconsistent DateTime behaviour

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to get the first monday of the next year and I am getting different output depending on what term I use:

```
$last1 = new \DateTime('first monday of January 2018');
/* outputs: 2018-01-01 (correct) */

$last2 = new \DateTime('first monday of January next year');
/* Outputs 2018-01-02 (wrong) */
```

So having it valid for every year I could do `new \DateTime('first monday of January '.date('Y') + 1);` but that seems "dirty". Is there something wrong with the second one? Not that THIS years first monday was the second, so I guess it gets parsed wrong?

Comment: This seems to be a bug because 2018-01-02 is not an monday. Or it is not possible to use `next year` in this format. Thing you have to use years as numbers

Comment: You can fix this with: `$last2 = new \DateTime('first monday of january next year -1 day')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP doc :

> Relative statements are always processed after non-relative statements

On the first expression there is both relative and non relative statements, the "2018" gets processed first and then the relatives statements "first day of January" is calculated after the modification applied, year 2018.

On the other hand the second expression is only based on relative statement. "first monday of January" will give the first first monday of January of the current year and then the next year will be applied.

You can split the relative statement in two using `modify`

```
$last2 = new \DateTime('next year');
$last2->modify('first monday of January');
```

Your code will also work, you can choose with one you prefer